# What is the easiest way to embed a bluetooth to any device?

Tags: android, bluetooth, hardware, remote-control

For example I have a speaker with buttons: volume up, down, play, pause, next, previous.
I want to embed into this speaker a blutooth feature to simulate buttons pressing.
For controlling I will use a mobile phone (android), controlling application I can create by myself.
I have no expierence in electronic, but I can try.
Easy solutions would also be wellcome. Are there any easy to integrate universal solutions I can buy?

I also have an arduino (it is too big for my purpose) and can use for prototyping. I have a bluetooth board http://www.bluesoleil.com/products/H0002201304270003.html

Answer (score -1):

I will try but it is a shot in the dark. I think that you need to try to remove the buttons and plug the Arduino ports instead. Buttons usually are making a short circuit, so you can connect an output of one of the Arduino ports, and set it high. when you want a click set it to low for few milis, and then high again. Good luck!